# Bone selection in edit mode is no longer working

Tags: bones

I can no longer select a complete bone from its body in edit mode. It only selects the bone end points. I have to use the outliner to select a complete bone.

This only happens on my main computer, both version 2.77 and 2.78. I have installed blender 2.78 on a second computer and things work fine. Has anybody else experienced this? Been looking around in console and input short cuts but I'm lost.

Comment: Does this happens in pose mode or weight paint mode too?

Comment: If you post the .blend using Blend Exchange we can take a look. Also, what happens when you load factory settings?

Comment: In pose mode everything is all good. I have reset to factory settings a few times now without luck. Some times it will work until I deselect every bone, then it stoppes again. I think I might try to reinstall blender. I have tried a repair from install file without luck.

Comment: @SveinArild Could you please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Check in the inspector that you haven't deselected the mouse icon on the bone as this stops objects from being selected.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I agree, but adding an image, to better show what you mean, as an example, would improve your answer

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to select in python? If so then the below script does it:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
C.object.data.edit_bones[0].select = True #select the root bone
```